# A dice is thrown six times, Find the probablity of getting the six numbers in any order.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

For example, getting all the posible numbers (from 1 to 6) in ascendant or descendant order is $\dfrac{2}{6^{6}}$, because the only pisibilities are (1,2,3,4,5,6) and (6,5,4,3,2,1).

But, i don't understand what is the difference when you want to get the six numbers in any order and also, the probability of only getting odd numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, there are $6!$ ways to order the six possible numbers so...  Note: I have no idea what your comment about the odd numbers has to do with the question.

Comment: So, $\dfrac{6!}{6^{6}}$ which is $\dfrac{5!}{6^{5}}$

Comment: The question about the odd numbers is for the probability of  getting only odd numbers when the dice is thrown six times. I think the answer is $(\dfrac{3}{6})^6$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

The possile arrangements for the six numbers are simply the [**permutations**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) that is $6!$